Analytical solution to fraction of remaining mass in system described by advection-diffusion equation
I'm solving the advection-diffusion equation numerically, for a partially absorbing boundary condition, and I'm interested in the fraction of "mass" that has escaped the system as a function of time.
The PDE is:
$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = K \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial x^2} - v\frac{\partial C}{\partial x},$$
where $C$ is a concentration, $K$ is the (constant) diffusivity, and $v$ is the (constant) advection velocity. We can separately talk about the diffusive and advective fluxes,
$$ j_D = -K\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}, \;\;\; j_A = vC,$$
and my boundary conditions are that $j_D(x=0)=0$, and $C\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$. My initial condition at time $t=0$ is a Dirac delta at some position $x_0$, and I always have $v < 0$ such that the distribution of mass is being advected towards the boundary at $x=0$, and at the same time the distribution is broadening because of diffusion.
The remaining mass in the system is given by $M(t)=\int_0^\infty C(x, t)$, and I am interested in the functional form of the fraction of mass that has left the system, i.e.,
$$f(t) = \frac{M(0) - M(t)}{M(0)}. $$
From numerical solutions, and by a bit of trial and error with different types of asymmetric sigmoid functions, I found that the CDF of a log-normal distribution can be fitted very nicely to $f(t)$. Just for completeness, the CDF of the log-normal is given by
$$ P(t) = \frac{1}{2}\bigg[1 + \mathrm{erf}\bigg( \frac{\ln (t) - \mu}{\sigma \sqrt{2}} \bigg) \bigg], $$
where $\mathrm{erf}$ is the error function, and the results of the numerical calculation and the curve fitting is shown in the plots below.

We note that the problem I've described is characterised by three parameters, $x_0$, $v$ and $K$, which together can form the dimensionless Péclet number, $Pe=v x_0 / K$. What I've found is that the procedure of fitting the CDF of the log-normal works very well for $Pe \gg 1$, but not when the Péclet number is of order 1 or smaller. I show an example for $Pe=0.059$ below:

I've also found that for $Pe \gg 1$, the parameter $\sigma$ in the fitted log-normal CDF is very well approximated by $\sigma = \sqrt{2/Pe}$, while I haven't found a similar clean relationship of $\mu$.
So, we finally get to the questions:

Is it possible to show analytically, or otherwise argue, that the lognormal CDF should be a good approximation of my result?
Is there a reason why it should work well for $Pe \gg 1$, but not otherwise?
Is there another fitted function that would work well for smaller values of $Pe$?

Intuitively, I think that for $Pe \gg 1$ (advection-dominated), then the distribution is being represented approximately by a Gaussian, that is widening as it is being absorbed. If we had $K=0$, the CDF of the Gaussian distribution would be the exact solution, but since the distribution is widening, we need an asymmetric sigmoid function of some sort.
For $Pe \ll 1$ (diffusion-dominated), the absorption would be very slow (since the absorption is driven by advection only), and therefore the distribution would have time to approach the steady state solution ($t=\infty$) of the advection-diffusion equation with no-flux boundary condition, which is an exponentially decaying concentration away from the boundary:
$$ C_{\infty}(x) = C_0 \mathrm{e}^{-xv/K}, $$
where $C_0$ is the concentration at the boundary. So in the case of $Pe \ll 1$, presumably the time-development I seek is described by the integral over a widening exponential distribution, rather than the integral over a widening Gaussian distribution.
This is about as far as I've come in my reasoning.
Any hints, suggestions, insights, references to literature, etc. would be much appreciated.

A minor point: Shouldn't your definition of $j_D$ have a minus sign in it?

Yes indeed, thanks.

How far did you get trying to solve the equation exactly? When you switch to $\xi=x\pm vt$ you'll find the diffusion equation. When you mirror $C(\xi)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, you can solve the equation using the cosine transform and automatically solve the Neumann boundary condition at zero.

My problem is that I have virtually no experience with solving PDEs analytically, so I didn't try anything like that. But isn't it a problem that the location of the boundary at x=0 will be changing with time if you make that change of coordinates? (Edit: Nevermind, I see what you mean, you mirror about x=0 so the boundary stays put.)

Wait a minute, I think you are right, the location of the boundary would change. Therefore, you have to keep working in the original variable $x$. This makes things slightly more annoying as the cosine transform of the first derivative depends on $C(0)$, while the cosine transform of the second derivative depends on $C'(0)=0$.
